# Communicate Android app with python Django web server

Tags: python, android, django-rest-framework, retrofit

I am creating a mobile app, I want to access a web server that is implemented in Python Django. I found that there is Retrofit in android to communicate with a web server. My question is that whether I have to write Client REST API and Server REST API both.

As I am considering that I will write REST API using Retrofit (Client REST API).
And then write a REST API for my server in python Django (Server API).

I am really confused about what will be the way to communicate with my server that is developed in python Django. And up to what limit I have control on server i.e how much an android app can control(create a database in web server, perform CRUD operations)

Thanks!

Comment: You can follow this example: https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/06/retrofit-2-crud-android-example.html

Comment: Is there a difference between Http Client and Http Serverver

Comment: Is it right that Http client make request to retrieve some data from server. In case of Android app we ust pass URL to our GET method and Retrive result in Form of JSON ( If Retrofit is itself REST API I don't know??) And we then use it Irrespective of language used at Web Server ?? Please Explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is quite simply, independent of the language of your server, basically if your server can respond with a json, you can use Retrofit2 and POST, GET, UPDATE, DELETE, etc...

Comment: Should I have to write REST API or just use it as an android developer? Real confusion is that should I write REST API or should only use it using Retrofit? @Azhagthott

Comment: I think you are confusing some concepts, Retrofit2 is a just HttpClient to connect to your API

Comment: ok Am I right Please verify! That Using Retrofit I will just use GET, POST etc.  Which in turn activate the respective methods in REST server to retrieve data or update or delete data. Here I am just calling those API written on web server for updation deleteion etc. ???